# watched her blow up her carefully curated image of refined privilege

Tags: word-meaning

**Growing up Ivanka**

> I met Ivanka Trump at an all-girls school on the Upper East Side, and we were inseparable for more than a decade. Gradually, though, our differences divided us-"Why would you tell me to read a book about fucking poor people?" she once asked-and I **watched her blow up her carefully curated image of refined privilege** to embrace her father wholesale.

Source: Vanity Fair

What does the phrase "watched her blow up her carefully curated image of refined privilege" mean? The keys words that I don't understand well is "blow" and "curated." So let me guess: "blow" refers to "enlarge to an extreme extent while "curated" means "selected." Am I on the right track?

Comment: "Blow up" is the verb in question here.

Comment: I saw "blow" and "blow up" as equals here.  You've not answered my question.

Comment: *Blow* and *blow up* are not the same thing.  You need to look up the phrasal verb *blow up* like randomhead says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Blow up" means to explode. It is used metaphorically here, i.e. to suddenly and violently destroy.

"Curated" means to carefully craft or select something or things for presentation. It is used here to mean that she has built up her image carefully over time and took care to maintain it.

According to this source, Ivanka spent time crafting an image of herself that she was refined and classy in a way that comes from power or money (or other forms of privilege). This image is suddenly shattered by the question she asks because of how unrefined, crass and rude it is as a question.